# Git color not visible through Ubuntu in WSL

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have modified the color of my shell thanks to this tutorial : 
https://medium.com/@jgarijogarde/make-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10-look-like-the-ubuntu-terminal-f7566008c5c2

It is great, nevertheless, I can no anymore see my active branch on GIT.

[image]

In the properties, I don't understand how to choose the right slot to modify the color of the text.

[image]

Would someone have an idea ?

Comment: oh no the dialog... je ne parle pas français...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I long ago wrote this registry file that you can give a try. The colors are tweaked a bit if you don't mind. This worked for me with a beautiful look.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Values stored as 00-BB-GG-RR
;[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_bash.exe]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\C:_Program Files_WindowsApps_CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2018.817.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc_ubuntu.exe]
"CodePage"=dword:000001b5

; BLACK DGRAY
"ColorTable00"=dword:00240A30
"ColorTable08"=dword:00cfd7d3
; BLUE LBLUE
;"ColorTable01"=dword:00a46534
"ColorTable01"=dword:00cf9f72
"ColorTable09"=dword:00ffbf8e
; GREEN LGREEN
;"ColorTable02"=dword:00069a4e
"ColorTable02"=dword:0034e28a
"ColorTable10"=dword:0068ff9f
; CYAN LCYAN
;"ColorTable03"=dword:009a9806
"ColorTable03"=dword:00e2e234
"ColorTable11"=dword:00ffff68
; RED LRED
;"ColorTable04"=dword:000000cc
"ColorTable04"=dword:002929ef
"ColorTable12"=dword:005252ff
; MAGENTA LMAGENTA
;"ColorTable05"=dword:007b5075
"ColorTable05"=dword:00a87fad
"ColorTable13"=dword:00ff9aff
; YELLOW LYELLOW
;"ColorTable06"=dword:0000a0c4
"ColorTable06"=dword:004fe9fc
"ColorTable14"=dword:006fffff
; LGRAY WHITE
;"ColorTable07"=dword:00cfd7d3
"ColorTable07"=dword:00eceeee
"ColorTable15"=dword:00ffffff
```

Save the above content into a text file with the extension `.reg`, and double click the file. Then you can see the effects.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) How and where should I put these lines ??

Comment: Ok nice ! Just to be sure, can you confirm me it is working for Ubuntu in WSL ?

Comment: @FrancNovation Yes, as long as you're launching WSL via the Ubuntu sticker in the Start Menu (not `bash.exe`).

Comment: Oups, @iBug I'm not getting what you have :-/. How can I cancel the registry ?

Comment: @FrancNovation Try resetting the "Screen background" and "Popup background" to the 1st slot, and "Screen text" and "Popup text" to the 8th slot. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFN1x.png)

Comment: In a first time, I got this result (see the following image) when I applied the register script : [image](https://ibb.co/rt3wzBF). But, after applying the last adjustment of **@iBug**, it is perfect !

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution, especially useful if you installed WSL through non-Microsoft Store means, is to swap the first and third colors. The first color should be purple, and the third color should be green-ish. Remember to set your Screen Background and Popup Background to the first color.

This should solve your git color issues.

Answer (score 0):

above didnt help me at all, but i found a simple git config color switch to solve my readability issues for the dark red in git status.

inside the wsl ubuntu terminal:

```
git config --global color.branch.remote "red bold"
git config --global color.status.untracked "red bold"
git config --global color.status.changed "red bold"
```